# Why TexStudio convert my .eps images to .pdf? Can I avoid that?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps, epstopdf

When I build my pdf presentation with texstudio it uses epstopfd and convert all my eps images to .pdf, keeping the originals.

My img folder duplicate the size beacause of that. Can I avoid that conversion and use the eps file only? Or another format that would not be converted.

Comment: you need to convert to pdf at some point to include them in the document if you are using pdflatex (which can not include eps)

Comment: you could of course delete the eps and only have pdf versions, unless you need the eps for some other use. (note this is unrelated to texstudio which is just the editor you are using for the tex files)

Comment: As I use Overleaf and it doesn't leave any traces of that kind of conversion I thought it was only with texstudio. So If I will use pdflatex in my tex file it will alway convert any images to pdf? My concert is because my dissertation model has a limitation and my institution recommend to only use eps files for images, but if they will be converted to pdf what is the difference to use pdf images from the beggining?

Comment: as I say either you convert the eps to pdf first or (more complicated, pdftex will call epstopdf in the background to convert them, but it makes no difference really) If you delete the pdfs it is slower as it has to re-make them.

Comment: Thank you! Could you write your answer outside comments for me to choose it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert to pdf at some point to include them in the document if you are using pdflatex (which can not include eps). If you want to save space and you do not need the files for other reasons you can delete the EPS files and just include the PDF directly.